# How to make shell script to write input on existing file

Tags: bash, shell

i need to make a sh script to ask for input and then write to existing file.

```
#!/bin/bash
sed '15isometext' settings.xml > test/settings1.xml
```

this is the code.

The script ask for "15isometext" input. "15" is number of line, "i" is fo insert and "sometext" the text i need to replace and save to file.

It's possible?

Thank you

Comment: It appears you are completely lost. First, you need to parse `15isometext` into `15`, `i`, and `sometext` in a flexible manner that presumably handles any line number, a flag for `i` and then the remainder as `text`. Passing input as the first argument to the script, you could do something like `num=$(grep -o "^[0-9]*" <<<"$1")`, for the flag `i`, you could do `tmp="${1#*${num}}"; flag=${tmp:0:1}` and finally `text=${tmp:1}`, then with the input separated, you can operate on the line `num` to do whatever `flag` means with `text`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from the comment. If I understand your question and you want to take `15isometext` as input and then change *line-15* of the target file to `sometext` saving the resulting file after the change (or replace in some manner that isn't entirely clear), then you have to do some work on `15isometext` before you can call `sed`. Specifically, you need to parse/separate `15isometext` into `15` (so you know which line to operate on), `i` so you know you will input in some fashion, and finally `sometext` so you know what text you will be inserting or replacing in the existing file.

You can handle that in various ways, but I suspect you would also like to be able to handle `2isomemoretext` and `2345istillmoretext` as well. In addition to separating the values, you also need a few validity checks. You need to validate that the number you get from `15isometext` is a valid *integer*. You need to check that the file you are attempting to change (1) *exists*; and (2) it has at least the required *number of lines* (15 in your case).

Putting all that together, you could do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash -- norc

[ -z $1 -o -z $2 ] && {  ## validate 2 arguments given
    printf "error: insufficient input, usage: %s string file\n" "${0//*\/}"
    exit 1
}

declare -i num=0
num=$(grep -o "^[0-9]*" <<< "$1")
[ "$num" -eq "$num" >/dev/null 2>&1 ] || {  ## validate num is integer
    printf "error: no integer found in '%s'\n" "$1"
    exit 1
}

[ ! -f "$2" -o "$(wc -l < "$2")" -lt "$num" ] && {  ## validate file length
    printf "error: file has less than '%s' lines.\n" "$num"
}

tmp="${1#*${num}}"
flag="${tmp:0:1}"
text="${tmp:1}"

if ! sed -i "${num}s/^.*$/$text/" "$2"  ## adjust to ins/replace as needed
then
    printf "error: substitution for line '%s' - failed.\n" "$num"
fi
```

As a test you can create a file with say 20 blank lines:

```
$ printf "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" > blankfile.txt
```

Then call the script on `blankfile.txt`, e.g.:

```
$ bash replacelinetext.sh 15isometext blankfile.txt
```

Finally confirm that it did insert `sometext` at line `15`

```
$ nl -b a blankfile.txt
     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
     6
     7
     8
     9
    10
    11
    12
    13
    14
    15  sometext
    16
    17
    18
    19
    20
```

Look this over and let me know if that was what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i 's/old/new/g' file.txt
```

That is what you need. Make note of the -i option to write back to file

You can work out the rest yourself